# Why can't I edit some questions?

Tags: support, editing

Like this one: [What is the principal argument of $-5-5i$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/635836/what-is-the-principal-argument-of-5-5i)

I don't see any option to edit it, to improve formatting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

But you can see edit on other questions? It could be because there is an edit already waiting for approval, so you cannot do anything until the edit is accepted or rejected.